# Cookie header appears twice when added in BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When the following IHttpModule is registered I get duplicate cookie headers for cookie_BeginRequest.

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest+=(sender, e) =>
            {
                SetValues("BeginRequest");
            };
        context.PreSendRequestContent+=(sender, e) =>
            {
                SetValues("PreSendRequestContent");
            };
    }

    static void SetValues(string name)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        var httpCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie_" + name, "cookie_value");
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("header_" + name, "header_value");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

I would expect to see the following headers:

> header_BeginRequest: header_value
>
> Set-Cookie: cookie_BeginRequest=cookie_value; path=/
>
> header_PreSendRequestContent: header_value
>
> Set-Cookie: cookie_PreSendRequestContent=cookie_value; path=/

Instead I see (note the duplicate Set-Cookie cookie_BeginRequest):

> header_BeginRequest: header_value
>
> Set-Cookie: cookie_BeginRequest=cookie_value; path=/
>
> Set-Cookie: cookie_BeginRequest=cookie_value; path=/
>
> header_PreSendRequestContent: header_value
>
> Set-Cookie: cookie_PreSendRequestContent=cookie_value; path=/

The headers above were extracted from Fiddler to exclude the browser being the source of the problem.
I have stepped through the code and it appears that the BeginRequest event is only firing once per request. This is backed up by the fact that the header_BeginRequest header only appears once. I have also checked that the module is only registered once. The tests were all run under IIS Express and .Net 4.5.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I think you are in a scenario where begin request is called twice, See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518814/how-to-limit-httpmodule-with-only-one-call-per-request for a possible work around.